# How to get the frame rate in android exoplayer programmatically?

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, exoplayer

I want to get the live stream frame rate using android exoplayer programmatically.
I did try following code to get the frame rate.

```
       exo_player.addAnalyticsListener(new AnalyticsListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTracksChanged(EventTime eventTime, TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {
            if(trackGroups!=null && !trackGroups.isEmpty()){
                for(int i=0;i<trackGroups.length;i++){
                    for(int j=0;i<trackGroups.get(i).length;j++){
                        float videFrame = trackGroups.get(i).getFormat(j).frameRate;
                        Log.e("videoFrame",String.valueOf(videFrame));
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
    });
```

but in my code, i can get -1. this is wrong.
Is there a way to get the video frame in exoplayer programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the index you gave to `get()` as a parameter belongs to a video segment? Maybe iterating the track groups with a for loop like below might help you.

```
for (i in 0 until trackGroups.length) {
     val videoFrame = trackGroups.get(i).getFormat(i).frameRate
     Log.i("videoFrame", "$videoFrame")
}
```

Comment: i did try this way. but i cant get correct value. it was also -1.